# How to get Iterator List By Form Submission in Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, ognl

This is my Java Class. The `processOrderMap` is a `ArrayList` with `HashMap` Type. This List iterated using iterator in `jsp`. I want to get iterated list in java class when form submission. I used

```
"processOrderMap[%{#ctr.index}].processPositionGrid"
```

the above code as a select box name, but it is not working.

```
public String addProcessOrderGridDetails() {
    try {
        HashMap hmap = new HashMap();//desc,suppartno,qnty,total
        hmap.put("routeIdGrid", routeId);
        hmap.put("routeNoGrid", routeNo);
        hmap.put("routeDescGrid", routeDesc);
        hmap.put("routeListGrid", routeGridList);
        hmap.put("processPositionGrid", processPositionList);

        processOrderMap.add(hmap);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception in addProcessOrderGridDetails Method of productionRouteAction" + e);
    }
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

This is my jsp page...

```
<s:iterator value="processOrderMap" status="ctr">
    <tr>
        <td style="" class="">

            <s:property value="#ctr.count"/>
        </td>
        <td style="" class="">&nbsp;<s:hidden theme="simple" 
                                              id="%{'routeNoGrid' + #ctr.index}" 
                                              name="processOrderMap[%{#ctr.index}].routeNoGrid" 
                                              value="%{routeNoGrid}"/>

            <s:hidden theme="simple" id="%{'routeIdGrid' + #ctr.index}" 
                      name="processOrderMap[%{#ctr.index}].routeIdGrid" 
                      value="%{routeIdGrid}"/>
            <s:property value="routeNoGrid"/>
        </td>

        <td style="">
            <s:select theme="simple" data-rel="chosen" 
                      id="%{'processPositionGrid' + #ctr.index}"
                      name="processOrderMap[%{#ctr.index}].processPositionGrid" 
                      list="processPositionGrid"
                      listKey="id" listValue="name"
                      headerKey="0" headerValue="--SELECT--"
                      cssClass="required input-medium selectMap" />
        </td>

        <td>
            <s:select theme="simple" data-rel="chosen" id="%{'routeListGrid' + #ctr.index}"
                      name="processOrderMap[%{#ctr.index}].routeListGrid" list="routeListGrid"
                      listKey="id" listValue="name" multiple="true"
                      headerKey="0" headerValue="--SELECT--"
                      cssClass="required" />

        </td>
    </tr>
</s:iterator>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `#ctr.index` is for indexed lists. The map should be accessed by the key.

```
"processOrderMap['processPositionGrid']"
```

Comment: actually i want to get the processOrderMap List in java Class